# How to specify label the categorical column using label of train data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

So i use some data to make model of random forest. There is multiple categorical columns and I change them to numerical using sklearn LabelEncoder. For example 'male' and 'female' with be label as '0' and '1' respectively. Then I use the model to predict single data. Before the data being predicted, I also change the categorical to numerical. Then I realize the label always same for single data even categorical data is different. For example(single data), male and female being labeled as '0', and the others also same. This make my model unusable. Should i just make label manual or have some idea?

some of the code

```
label = LabelEncoder()
train_data['gender'] = label.fit_transform(train_data['gender'])
train_data['ever_married'] = label.fit_transform(train_data['ever_married'])
train_data['work_type'] = label.fit_transform(train_data['work_type'])
train_data['Residence_type'] = label.fit_transform(train_data['Residence_type'])
train_data['smoking_status'] = label.fit_transform(train_data['smoking_status'])
```

Comment: try count encoder https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/count.html

Comment: using labelencoder in this fashion will result in multiple meanings to a number i.e. 0 can mean 'male' and also 'married' , ... etc.,

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you are using always the method fit_transform **on the same encoder instance**

You should use a **different** label encoder for every category with the method `fit`, and then transform your single instance with that encoder, with its `transform` method encoder

```
encoder_gender = LabelEncoder()
train_data_gender = encoder_gender.fit_transform(train_data['gender'])
encoder_gender.transform(single_data)
```

If you call the `fit_transform` with the same encoder instance (`label` in your case) on different categories, you are changing every time the meaning of that encoder and the way it encodes the data